# Meteor async function in meteor-method with database update

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

for the last few hours, I have been trying to get an async method to play nice with meteor methods and its database.

While using `wrapAsync` works great for simple method calls, I struggling with getting it to work in this case.

Any help would be much appreciated.

https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-wrapAsync

The async method in question:

```
chargebee.subscription.list({
  limit : 5, 
  "plan_id[is]" : "basic", 
  "status[is]" : "active",
  "sort_by[asc]" : "created_at"
}).request(function(error,result){
  if(error){
    //handle error
    console.log(error);
  }else{
    for(var i = 0; i < result.list.length;i++){
      var entry=result.list[i]
      console.log(entry);
      var subscription = entry.subscription;
      var customer = entry.customer;
      var card = entry.card;
    }
  }
});
```

What I tried and didn't work:

```
    try {
        var result = Meteor.wrapAsync(chargebee.subscription.list, chargebee.subscription)({
            limit: 5,
            "customer_id[is]": Meteor.userId(),
            "status[is]": "active",
            "sort_by[asc]": "created_at"
        }).request();

        if (result.list[0]) {
            const subscription = result.list[0].subscription;
            console.log("quantity", subscription.plan_quantity);

            Subs.update(
                {
                    owner_id: this.userId
                }, {
                    $set: {
                        quantity: subscription.plan_quantity
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap in `Meteor.wrapAsync` the async method itself. In your code you're wrapping the `chargebee.subscription.list` only, and it *isn't* async (based on your example).

You should wrap `.request()` method instead (not its call):

```js
// Call to `subscription.list()` extracted
// for better understanding
try {
  var list = chargebee.subscription.list({
    limit: 5,
    "customer_id[is]": Meteor.userId(),
    "status[is]": "active",
    "sort_by[asc]": "created_at"
  });
  var result = Meteor.wrapAsync(list.request)();
  // process result
} catch(error) {
  // process error
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either. It is not doing anything on `Meteor.wrapAsync(list.request)();`. Everything after this call isn't executed.

Comment: I'm getting this error server side: ``TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasIdInUrl' of undefined
   at RequestWrapper.request ([...]\node_modules\chargebee\lib\chargebee.js:100:34)``

Comment: When I use it with other api points, it is returning `{status: 'pending'}`

Comment: @user2693017 The question was about a correct way to use `Meteor.wrapAsync`, not about using `chargebee` and/or its issues.

Comment: Yeah, but in the instance of two methods depending on each other. Not a simple method call ;)

Comment: @user2693017 Are you using `chargebee-node` npm module or `taketime:chargebee-meteor` package?